# How to parse Objective-C code within a Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parsing, clang

I am writing a Mac OS X desktop application in which I want to be able to parse fragments of Objective-C such as variable and method declarations, as well as full Objective-C header and source files.

It looks to me as if I should be making use of Clang to do this, but I could do with some pointers and examples on how to integrate it as a library in my project, and how to invoke it to parse strings and files.

Can anyone provide me with any help on this?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want `libclang`, code browsable at http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/libclang/ (though you'll need to checkout the entire Clang repo to build it). There's very little documentation around on it, sadly. There is a presentation at http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/Gregor-libclang.pdf that might help kickstart things, but mostly just some hunting through the code is the way to go.

Clang is actually more modular than `libclang` provides for (you can import just the components you want). If you've adventurous, there are examples at http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/.

Comment: Thanks. I've got the llvm and clang code checked out and built based on the info at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html, and I can see the tools/libclang directory with the header files I need. Now I need to figure out how to incorporate this into my Xcode 4.2 project.